# Trigger display using getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the **"Dont have an account?"** line to trigger the display of `.registrybox` class when clicked. I have written down some script and it does not function. Script specifies that when **Dont have an account?** is clicked, `.loginbox` should disappear and be replaced w/ the `.registrybox` class code.

Those CSS `display: none` and `display: block` are written beforehand.

```js
function displayRegistry() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('.registrybox').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName('.loginbox').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: block;
}


}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.loginbox a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.registrybox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: trnaslate(-50%, -50%);
}
.registrybox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.registrybox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fb2525;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.registrybox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.registrybox {
  display: none;
}
select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="displayRegistry()">Dont have an account?</a>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="registrybox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
    <a hred="#">Already registered?</a>
    <select name="dobmonth">
      <option>month</option>
      <option value="january">January</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dobyear">
      <option>Year</option>
      <option value="2000">2006</option>
      <option value="2000">2005</option>
      <option value="2000">2004</option>
      <option value="2000">2003</option>
      <option value="2000">2002</option>
      <option value="2000">2001</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="2000">1999</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `getElementsByClassName()` returns an ***[array-like](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)*** object with matched class name, so you will need to get the element by using `[0]`...Also you don't need to use `.` period when using `getElementsByClassName()`

```js
function displayRegistry() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('registrybox')[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName('loginbox')[0].style.display = "none";
}
function displayLogin() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('registrybox')[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('loginbox')[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: block;
}


}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.loginbox a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.registrybox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: trnaslate(-50%, -50%);
}
.registrybox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.registrybox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fb2525;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.registrybox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.registrybox {
  display: none;
}
select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="displayRegistry()">Dont have an account?</a>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="registrybox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
    <a hred="#" onclick="displayLogin()">Already registered?</a>
    <select name="dobmonth">
      <option>month</option>
      <option value="january">January</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dobyear">
      <option>Year</option>
      <option value="2000">2006</option>
      <option value="2000">2005</option>
      <option value="2000">2004</option>
      <option value="2000">2003</option>
      <option value="2000">2002</option>
      <option value="2000">2001</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="2000">1999</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Or you can use `querySelector`...

```js
function displayRegistry() {
  document.querySelector('.registrybox').style.display = "block";
  document.querySelector('.loginbox').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: block;
}


}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.loginbox a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.registrybox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: trnaslate(-50%, -50%);
}
.registrybox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.registrybox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fb2525;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.registrybox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.registrybox {
  display: none;
}
select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">
  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="displayRegistry()">Dont have an account?</a>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="registrybox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
    <a hred="#">Already registered?</a>
    <select name="dobmonth">
      <option>month</option>
      <option value="january">January</option>
    </select>
    <select name="dobyear">
      <option>Year</option>
      <option value="2000">2006</option>
      <option value="2000">2005</option>
      <option value="2000">2004</option>
      <option value="2000">2003</option>
      <option value="2000">2002</option>
      <option value="2000">2001</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="2000">1999</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, but I tried to use the same drill over the **Already registered?** line from the registry box. Did not pay off. Any idea how to resolve that too?

Comment: I created another function `displayLogin` and appended `onclick="displayLogin()` code to the **Already registered** line. Just rehashed whatever I had written for `displayRegistry` with opposite effects (Registry disappearing and being replaced by the login form).

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your JS code.

1. document.getElementsByClassName() requires only the class name. You are adding '.' in front of the classname. This wrong.
2. document.getElementsByClassName() returns an array of elements. In your case, you need to select first element from this array. So you need to use [0] to get the desired value

```js
function displayRegistry() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('registrybox')[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName('loginbox')[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: block;
}


}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.loginbox a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.registrybox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: trnaslate(-50%, -50%);
}
.registrybox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.registrybox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fb2525;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.registrybox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.registrybox {
  display: none;
}
select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">

  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="displayRegistry()">Dont have an account?</a>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="registrybox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
    <a hred="#">Already registered?</a>
    <select name="dobmonth">
                        <option>month</option>
                        <option value="january">January</option>
                    </select>
    <select name="dobyear">
                        <option>Year</option>
                        <option value="2000">2006</option>
                         <option value="2000">2005</option>
                          <option value="2000">2004</option>
                           <option value="2000">2003</option>
                            <option value="2000">2002</option>
                             <option value="2000">2001</option>
                              <option value="2000">2000</option>
                               <option value="2000">1999</option>
                    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
function displayRegistry() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('registrybox')[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName('loginbox')[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.loginbox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  background-color: ;
  color: #fff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 50px 20px;
  display: block;
}


}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.loginbox p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.loginbox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fb2525;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.loginbox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.loginbox a:hover {
  color: red;
}
.registrybox {
  width: 320px;
  height: 420px;
  color: #fff;
  top: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: trnaslate(-50%, -50%);
}
.registrybox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.registrybox input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="text"],
[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #fb2525;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.registrybox input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  color: #000;
}
.registrybox a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkgrey;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.registrybox {
  display: none;
}
select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loginbox">

  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
    <a href="#">Forgot password?</a><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="displayRegistry()">Dont have an account?</a>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="registrybox">
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form>
    <p>Username</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username">
    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <p>Repeat Password</p>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
    <a hred="#">Already registered?</a>
    <select name="dobmonth">
                        <option>month</option>
                        <option value="january">January</option>
                    </select>
    <select name="dobyear">
                        <option>Year</option>
                        <option value="2000">2006</option>
                         <option value="2000">2005</option>
                          <option value="2000">2004</option>
                           <option value="2000">2003</option>
                            <option value="2000">2002</option>
                             <option value="2000">2001</option>
                              <option value="2000">2000</option>
                               <option value="2000">1999</option>
                    </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alternative with `jquery` u can use this i can't do it here because i can't add `jquery`

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/c728xbvp/2/)